# Open Source Socket Server

Tags: sockets, open-source

I am writing an iOS app that communicates with a remote computer using a socket stream. I am looking for an open source socket server that runs on the host computer that will read the data, and send it onto the host operating system.

So I am wondering if there is an open source "socket server" that is available for Windows (and other OS's) that does this. The server would basically read the incoming data and then pass it onto the operating system to handle. For example, if I send the remote computer the keystrokes Control C, and I have Notepad open, then I expect the copy command to be executed on the host computer.

Ideally the user will be able to configure the host server and set the port number, username, and password for the connection.

Notes:

- I don't want to use VNC as the server since it only supports a
  limited set of keystrokes
- I have no experience programming in Windows or Unix/Linux, and so
  don't have the knowledge to program a server on my own.

Comment: You're talking about a remote desktop application, which is very complicated (especially when you get to security). VNC is your best bet cross-platform, otherwise you'll have to recreate everything that it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what I was looking for in a networking library called Twisted. Twisted is an event-driven networking engine written in Python and licensed under the open source.

http://twistedmatrix.com

Looks like it is very easy to setup a networking server of any type using Twisted.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're basically talking about building a protocol that implements almost everything VNC does, plus whatever 'extra' your application needs.  If I was you, I'd spend a lot more time gathering and defining your requirements in **much** more detail rather than just thinking about Ctrl^c scenarios.

I'd be willing to bet that if you laid out your requirements for this 'socket server' you'll find that VNC and or Remote Desktop protocols will do what you need.

Oh, and by the way, the "socket server/client" portion of this question will end up being the easiest part :)  There are plenty of free examples of plain ole socket servers/clients.  **But** the details and difficulty always lies in the protocol that the server implements.  And in your case, interoperating with different OSes... this is a huge challenge.

**tl;dr;** Don't be too quick to dismiss VNC or Remote Desktop.